# Get All files on Google Drive API after a auth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, google-drive-api

I use Google Drive API, I connect me and I have the token. But I don't know how can get the list of file of my drive.

I use angular and a api Node.js. I don't find a good tutorial and the documentation of google have just javascript not node.js

Response is the token .

This is my code :

```
var url;
  var windowThatWasOpened;

  $http({method: 'POST', url: '/api/url'}).then(function(response) {
        url = response.data;
  });

    $scope.myFunc = function(e) {
     windowThatWasOpened = $window.open(url, "Please sign in with Google", "width=500px,height:700px");     
    };

      window.onmessage = function(e) {
        if(windowThatWasOpened){
          windowThatWasOpened.close();
        }
        var urlWithCode = e.data;        
        var idx = urlWithCode.lastIndexOf("code=");
        var code = urlWithCode.substring(idx + 5).replace("#","");
        var url = "/api/oauth2callback?code=" + code;
        $http.get(url).then(function(response) { console.log("token ok..");  });

        $http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/").then(function(response){
          console.log(response);
        });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to list files using Drive API and Nodejs, then you can definitely use [Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs). This show basic listing of files:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/drive-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'drive-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
  // Drive API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listFiles);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listFiles(auth) {
  var service = google.drive('v3');
  service.files.list({
    auth: auth,
    pageSize: 10,
    fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var files = response.files;
    if (files.length == 0) {
      console.log('No files found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Files:');
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        console.log('%s (%s)', file.name, file.id);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Remember that you have to follow these steps before running the application:

Step 1: Turn on the Drive API

Step 2: Install the client library

Step 3: Set up the sample

Step 4: Run the sample

To further familiarize yourself with Drive API and Nodejs, here are the following documents:

- [Google APIs Client for Node.js documentation](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/#google-apis-nodejs-client)
- [Drive REST API reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/)

Hope this helps.